# Reveal.js is not preserving html small tags within Markdown slides

Tags: fonts, markdown, reveal.js

Markdown is supposed to preserve HTML tags within Markdown blocks, but a `<small>` tag **within the markdown** of a Reveal.js slide is being converted to a plain `<p>` tag. I could make the entire slide from HTML code, but that’s not ideal for an occasional need for small text. Here’s the slide:

```html
<section data-markdown>
    # IA: **4a**

    Information Architecture uses **Cognitive Psychology** research

    - **Cognitive load**: how much information we can process at any time—avoiding information overload ([rule of 7](http://neuromavin.com/cognitive-limits-social-networks-and-dunbars-number/)).
    - **Mental models**: the assumptions users have—information is easier to discover in familiar places.
    - **Decision making**: the cognitive process of making a choice or selecting an option—IA helps make decisions by providing contextual information at key points.

    <small>
    [The Magical Number Seven… George A. Miller (1956)](http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Miller/)  
    </small>
</section>
```

This generates the following HTML `p` tag instead of a `small` tag within a paragraph:

```html
<p>
  <a href="http://psychclassics.yorku.ca/Miller/">The Magical Number Seven… George A. Miller (1956)</a>
</p>
```

Why (or where/how) is the `<small>` tag being stripped out? I've tried adding a `data-markdown` attribute to the small tag, but the tag is still stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<textarea data-template>` inside the `<section>` tag. For example:

```
<section data-markdown>
<textarea data-template>

# Does this work?

<small>Smaller text</small>

</textarea>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes thanks that works - it is [suggested in the reveal guide](https://revealjs.com/markdown/) and renders the Markdown as well as the HTML properly, but I've only ever used `<section data-markdown>` until now.